# When is multiplication of large dense matrices useful?

Tags: matrix, multiplication

Is there a scenario or application that uses multiplication of large dense matrices? Something like computer vision?

Comment: Also asked at:https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-are-the-most-important-applications-of-large-dense-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides computer vision, matrix multiplication is being heavily used in computer graphics. For example, when you were typing in your question, if anything moved onto your screen that was matrix multiplication in action.

Another application I can think of lies in computer and internet security. For example, if you have ever done any online shopping or banking chances are there was some matrix multiplication going on in the background to protect your password or PIN number.

Also, if you have ever taken any operations research course, you may be impressed by how often matrix multiplication is being used with the linear programming technique.

That's all right off the top of my head. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot. And do you have any ideas about such a specific operation of application where matrix multiplication is significant important? something like 3d projection? I mean could you please make it more specific. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For example, you can read a paper like [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=63499&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D63499).

Comment: Well, for graphics it is a 4x4 x Nx4 so not really "large in all dimensions" :-( What algorithm are you referring to in the PIN protection more precisely?